# How do I set the template_name using generic.TemplateView based on is_authenticated vs is_superuser?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-authentication, login-required

I'm using Django.
I'm attempting to set the template to use based on the django user access level.
As you can see I'm using the LoginRequiredMixin and generic.TemplateView.

This is what I'd like to do:

This code is used in views.py.

```
class TableView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    if user.is_superuser == True:
        template_name = 'achtable.html'
    elif user.is_authenticated:
        template_name = 'userachtable.html'
```

Unfortunatly it appears I can't access the user. in this manner.

In views.py I also have the api views which work as expected based on the user authentication.  It is a follows:

```
class MyList(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser==True:
            queryset = ImportantStuff.objects.all()
            return queryset
        elif self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            queryset = ImportantStuff.objects.all()
            return queryset.filter(claimed=False)
```

Any input is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need the request so do as you've done in MyList (use a function).

```
class TableView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
             return 'superadmin/path/template.html'
        return 'regular/path/template.html'
```

---

By the way:

```
if self.request.user.is_superuser==True:
```

is the same than (better version):

```
if self.request.user.is_superuser:
```

And if you use `LoginRequiredMixin`, you already know that the user is authenticated so your second `if` statement is useless.

Here is `MyList` updated:

```
class MyList(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return ImportantStuff.objects.all()
        return ImportantStuff.objects.filter(claimed=False)
```